# how to implement custom field with Audit.Net entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, audit-trail, audit.net

I'm new to Audit.net. I successfully configure it in my project.

But now, i need to extend it to save extra information like requesterID and a comment write on the view page.

my case : 
Entity mapped to Entity_AT

```
Entity {
    [Key]
    int     ID
    string  label
}
```

```
Entity_AT {
    [Key]
    int      ATID
    int      ID
    string   label
    int      ATFlag
    datetime ATCreationDate
    string   RequesterID
    string   ATComment
}
```

```
public void Add(TEntity obj, string RequesterId)
{
   _dbSet.Add(obj);
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

```
[AuditDbContext(Mode = AuditOptionMode.OptOut, IncludeEntityObjects = false, AuditEventType = "{database}_{context}")]
public class MyDBContext : AuditIdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
}
```

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.DataProvider = new EntityFrameworkDataProvider()
{
    AuditTypeMapper = t => t == typeof(Entity) ? typeof(Entity_AT) : null,
    AuditEntityAction = (evt, entry, auditEntity) =>
    {
        var a = (dynamic)auditEntity;
        a.ATCreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        a.ATFlag = (entry.Action == "Insert") ? 1 : (entry.Action == "Update") ? 2 : (entry.Action == "Delete") ? 3 : 0;

        return true; // return false to ignore the audit
    }
};
```

I tried :

```
_context.AddAuditCustomField("RequesterId", requesterId);
_context.AddAuditCustomField("ATComment", "pippo");

_dbSet.Add(obj);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

but no results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have added the `"RequesterId"` custom field to the `AuditEvent`, but you are not mapping it to the `AuditEntity` property.

You should do the following on the entity action:

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.DataProvider = new EntityFrameworkDataProvider()
{
    AuditTypeMapper = t => t == typeof(Entity) ? typeof(Entity_AT) : null,
    AuditEntityAction = (evt, entry, auditEntity) =>
    {
        var a = (dynamic)auditEntity;
        a.ATCreationDate = ...;
        a.ATFlag = ...;

        a.RequesterID = evt.CustomFields["RequesterId"] as string;
        a.ATComment = evt.CustomFields["ATComment"] as string;

        return true; 
    }
};
```

Note you can alternatively use the Fluent API to configure the data provider with a cleaner syntax:

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseEntityFramework(_ => _
        .AuditTypeExplicitMapper(map => map
            .Map<Entity, Entity_AT>((evt, entry, auditEntity) =>
            {
                auditEntity.ATCreationDate = ...;
                auditEntity.ATFlag = ...;
                auditEntity.RequesterID = evt.CustomFields["RequesterId"] as string;
                auditEntity.ATComment = evt.CustomFields["ATComment"] as string;
            })));
```

Comment: understood
it works fine for me.
Thank you so much for the quick answer
Audit.net seems to be a pretty good framework, i keep it.

I think I will have other questions, but I prefer to browse documentation. I try hard, but people like you give me sense to continue. thank again